# Angular UI-Grid POST/PUT Example on a RestFull API via Angular ngResource

Tags: angularjs, rest, put, angular-ui-grid, insert-update

Showing grid is working perfect:

**FACTORY (excerpt)** works perfect

```
.factory('MyResource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(
        'http://my-rest-api/whatever/:id',
        {
            id: '@_id'
        },
        {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        }
    )})
```

**CONTROLLER (excerpt1)** works perfekt

```
$scope.myGrid.gridConfiguration = {..} 
$scope.myGrid.columnDefs = {..}
$scope.myGrid.data = MyResource.query();
```

**VIEW (excerpt)** works perfect

```
<div
    ui-grid="myGrid"
    ui-grid-edit
    ui-grid-cellNav
    class="gridMid">
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER (excerpt2) But Update does not Work:**

```
    $scope.myGrid.gridConfiguration.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
        //set gridApi on scope
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){

            // Following works
            $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'Edited (#' + rowEntity.id + '), Column: (' + colDef.name + ') New Value: (' + newValue + ') Old Value: (' + oldValue +")" ;
            **// THIS DOES NOT WORK**
            MyResource.update({id: rowEntity.id },rowEntity);

            // following works too
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
```

**Where is my mistake?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no mistakes, the REST-SERVER was not working properly.

For all, who want to test a DUMMY-REST-API with Angular UI-Grid and ngResource, I've prepared a repository here:

https://github.com/webia1/ANGULAR_SKELETON_VERTICAL_TABS

It uses HTTP-PUT to update a ressource.